# .NET Core Negotiate Authentication Scheme Does not Seem to Work

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

In my .NET 7 project, I have my authentication and authorization configured like the following:

```
        builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddNegotiate(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, _ => { })
            .AddCertificate(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                options => {
                    options.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
                    options.ValidateCertificateUse = true;
                    options.ValidateValidityPeriod = true;
                    options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents() {
                        OnAuthenticationFailed = InvalidCertificates.InvalidCertificateHandler,
                        OnCertificateValidated = ValidCertificates.ValidCertificateHandler
                    };
                });

        builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => {
            options
                .AddPolicy(AuthorizationsConstants.AuthenticatedUser,
                    policy => {
                        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                        policy.AuthenticationSchemes = new[] { NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme };
                        policy.Requirements.Add(new ValidCertificateRequirement());
                    });
            options
                .AddPolicy(AuthorizationsConstants.ReportAuthorization,
                policy => {
                    policy.Requirements.Add(new ReportAuthorizationRequirement());
                });
        });
```

On my local machine, the context.User in my authorization handlers has two Identities - a ClaimsIdentity and a WindowsIdentity.

My website is configured to use ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication.  This is because the IIS server is part of the domain, and all of the users have accounts in Active Directory to which their certificate is mapped.

When I initially deployed my code to the site, I received the error:  "The Negotiate Authentication handler cannot be used on a server that directly supports Windows Authentication. Enable Windows Authentication for the server and the Negotiate Authentication handler will defer to it."

So, I updated the site to enable Windows Authentication for the application.  Once I did that, the error went away.

When I used .NET Framework, IIS populated the user principal with information retrieved from Active Directory. However, this does not happen on my site.  The context.User in the Authorization handlers only has a single ClaimsIdentity.

To me, it appears that the AuthenticateAsync method is not called in Negotiate because I have a class the inherits IClaimsTransformation.  On my local machine, this class gets called twice:  once for the Negotiate scheme and once for the Certificate scheme.

I would like to access the claims for user populated by Active Directory - partially to ensure that the user has actually authenticated with the AD.

At this point, I'm at a total loss as to what is going on or how to fix it.

**Update**:

I updated the Failed Request Trace to log all HTTP status codes.  I believe that a relevant portion of the request is the following:

[image]

I'm guessing the main issue here is that because of the certificate mapping NTLM is set to false and, therefore, is not triggering the scheme because, well, negotiate is in the name.

So, I believe the next step is to probably come up with a custom Authentication scheme or is there something else I can use that I don't know about?

Comment: This may also be a problem with your configuration, here is an article about configure windows authentication in asp.net core that may help you: [Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: @samu If it is, I don't know where the disconnect is.  windows auth is installed and enabled for the application.  I checked the web.config.  Anonymous is turned off, windows auth is specifically enabled, it inherits clientCertificateMappingAuthentication.  I did a trace and client cert mapping is working and setting the user.  I think the issue is that NTLM is set to false which is screwing with the Negotiate auth scheme.

Comment: I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com, microsoft engineers will help find the root cause.